# How to construct the payload for Web API PATCH Method?

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API written in .NET Core.

The PATCH method uses [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument in the parameter:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public Account Patch(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Account> accountPath)
```

I am able to execute all the methods (GET, PUT, POST, PATCH) from Postman or Swagger UI, but I am having a difficulty executing the PATCH method from a .NET client application.

This is what I passed in to the Request Body for the PATCH method on Swagger UI or Postman:

```
[{"op": "replace","path": "/Name","value": "Test111"}]
```

How do I pass the above payload in .NET client application ?

When I do the below code, it doesn't give me an error, but the response was

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

This is my code:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
   var AccountPayload = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
      {"Name", "TEST111"}
   };
   var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AccountPayload);
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "https://localhost:5001/api/myAPI/1");
   request.Content = new StringContent(content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
   var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   return response; //--> response = StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `[{"op": "replace","path": "/Name","value": "Test111"}]` Is an array of objects, in this example, the one object in the array has 3 properties: `op`, `path` and `value`, your `AccountPayload` does not match this type of `json`. So it's probably failing to deserialize the `json` you are sending in your client.

Comment: Correct. How do I create this array payload to the Web API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question seems to be how to create this payload for the client to pass over to your api, I would suggest using a model class to represent your payload:

```
//Model class to represent one object in payload
public class MyPayload
{
    [JsonProperty("op")]
    public string Op {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string Path {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your example code, change to this:

```
var AccountPayload = new List<MyPayload>
{
   new MyPayload() { Op = "replace", Path = "/Name", Value = "Test111" }
};
```

Comment: This is possible, but JsonPatchDocument has the facilities to create patches built in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonPatchDocument<T>` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` nuget package to construct a patch

```
var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<Account>();
patchDoc.Replace(p => p.Name, "TEST111");
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc)); // outputs what you'd expect
```

This assumes you have the `Account` class (with `Name` property) as a strongly typed object on the client. If you don't have that, you can use the non-generic variant as follows:

```
var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDoc.Replace("/Name", "TEST111");
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have had issues with Patch in the past too. In my case these were solved with the X-Http-Method-Override header:

```
        if (request.Method == Method.PATCH)
        {
            request.AddHeader("X-Http-Method-Override", "PATCH");
            request.Method = Method.POST;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using JObject instead of JsonPatchDocument

Comment: Ryan Wilson's suggestion works. Thank you so much all !!